# set class in css or hover over 2 overlapping divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to give the hover-icon a class, so that the icon is the triggerinfo? The image is in gray when i hover it, it gets colored but I wan't to hover a text when is colored, when I going over the little icon. Is there a way overlapping the div with the triggerinfo class over the image, but not leaving the hover of the image. Like hover the div that is not visible and not leaving the hover effect colored ?

Thanks !

If it helps I can share the link to my website, but only as message not for the public post. It gets more visual, and I think better to understand what I mean.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".triggerinfo").mouseleave(function() {
    jQuery(this).next(".info").hide();
  });
  jQuery(".triggerinfo").hover(function() {
    jQuery(this).next(".info").toggle("fade");
  });
});
```

```css
.info {
    display: none;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    z-index: 1;
}
.triggerinfo {
    display: inline-felx;
    opacity: 0.1;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -50px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    z-index: 3;
}
.uk-overlay-icon:before {
    content: "\f0c9";
    position: absolute;
    top: 90%;
    left: 10%;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-top: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 1;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    text-align: center;
    color: #f69c00;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div data-uk-filter="dsgf" data-grid-prepared="true" style="position: absolute; box-sizing: border-box; padding-left: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; top: 0px; left: 0px; opacity: 1;">
    <div class="uk-panel">
        <div class="uk-panel-teaser">
            <figure class="uk-overlay uk-overlay-hover ">
                <img src="/wp-content/uploads/bilder/projekte/dsf.jpg" class="uk-overlay-grayscale" alt="dfsg">
                <div class="uk-overlay-panel uk-overlay-icon uk-overlay-fade"></div>
                <a class="uk-position-cover" href="/wp-content/plugins/widgetkit/cache/nuding-35281426b204ba8667e05928e60e8a11.jpg" data-lightbox-type="image" data-uk-lightbox="{group:'.wk-1b2a'}" title="dsfg"></a>
            </figure>
        </div>

        <div>
            <div class="triggerinfo">
                sdf
            </div>
            <div class="info">
                <h5>dsfg</h5>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I made a fiddle from your supplied code: https://jsfiddle.net/e8qd8gvf/ --- Could you please complete it to the point at where were able to see the things you're talking about? You could also provide screenshots of how you want it to look.

Comment: The fiddle works now as it should on my site: https://jsfiddle.net/e8qd8gvf/3/

Answer (score 0):

The [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e8qd8gvf/3/)`jsfiddle.net/e8qd8gvf/3/` works now as it should on my site. Now the thing is: on hover the img get colored and it appears a little icon in the bottom left coner, the trigger that is now under the img should be this little icon, because the icon is from the css definition in uk-overlay-icon (from the font awesome) 
I dont now how to set the info class on this icon. 
Or I was trying put an div with the info class over the img at the position of the icon and than trigger it, but than the colored effekt dont show when I trigger it, so I thought there must be a way to trigger the div on hover and not lose the colored effect, so the trigger div would trigger the Info and musst trigger the hover from the img at the same time

PS: Sorry for the long css !

Comment: This is not an answer - it's a comment. --- BTW it is your responsibility to provide us only with the code needed to debug your problem. More than 11.500 lines of CSS are definetly NOT needed!

Answer (score 0):

The `<figure>` element is intended to mark up diagrams, illustrations, photos, code examples and similar content, *"that can be moved away from the main flow of the document without affecting the document’s meaning"* (http://w3c.github.io/html-reference/figure.html).
Your way of using it seems to be against this specification.

It's your own responsibility to code according to specification and best practices.

---

I just opted with your provided example: https://jsfiddle.net/e8qd8gvf/4/

I moved the `uk-overlay-icon` outside of the figure, added the *toggle-info* class and put the `info` box inside it.

All that was left was adding some **CSS**:

```
.uk-position-cover { cursor: default; }
.uk-panel-teaser { position: relative; }
.toggle-info {
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute; bottom: 20px; left: 20px;
    width: 30px; height: 30px;
}
.toggle-info > .info {
    width: 150px; height: 150px;
    border: 2px solid red;
    position: absolute; bottom: -20px; left: 10px;
    transform: translateY(100%);
}
.toggle-info, .info { display: inline-block !important; }
.toggle-info.hidden, .info.hidden { display: none !important; }
```

as well as changing your **JS** to:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".uk-overlay").hover(
        function() {
            jQuery(this).next(".toggle-info").removeClass("hidden");
        },
        function() {
            jQuery(this).next(".toggle-info").addClass("hidden");
        }
    );
    jQuery(".toggle-info").hover(
        function() {
            jQuery(this)
                .removeClass("hidden")
                .children(".info").removeClass("hidden");
        },
        function() {
            jQuery(this)
                .addClass("hidden")
                .children(".info").addClass("hidden");
        }
    );
});
```

My solution is only showing you a way to accomplish things and is by far not "nice". You need to adapt it yourself and to specifications.